# Libreoffice / Openoffice Calc - Capturing multiple text cells to a single cell

Tags: libreoffice

I have been search far and wide and the closest I have come is the concat function but would really like something cleaner.

What I am trying to do is reference several cells that contain textual variable in a single cell.  Basically in the same context that you can specify = A1 + A2 but using text variable and not actually do the addition.
ex.
   `A       B         C         D 
1 bob      3
2 sue      4 
3 tom      bob + sue`

in cell B3 I can put   = A1  and will see the text "bob" shown there but if I put   =A1 + A2  I get an error message. I want to textually see "bob + sue". As well I want this to update if I later change sue to suzy.
I know concatenate(A1,A2)  will produce bobsue but that is not what I want. I'm looking more for something like having the contents of several cross referenced cells in another cell. If that makes any sense.

Why am I doing this?   I want to output this as CSV to use in a program to set default parameters. Some will get overridden and thus I want to keep the format.
There is a lot more to it but I could not possibly explain it all here.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `CONCATENATE(A1,' + ', A2)`? If you need something like `CONCAT(A1:A2)`, resulting in `bob + sue` (and `CONCAT(A1:A3)` in `bob + sue + tom`, you will need a macro.

Comment: hmmm did not know you could do that with concatenate.  I guess my goal is to keep it simple for the end user.  My example was just a simple +  but in some of the uglier cases it becomes: `( bob >  2) ? 3 :(bob >  1) ? 2 :1` as you can imagine trying to represent that using concat will be brutal.  The goal is just to have the reference to one or more variable linked to a single cell.